# Empty Xml Document response from Api

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, html-agility-pack

I need information from imdb unoffical api "omdbapi".I am sending link in correct but when I get response the document is null.I am using htmlagiltypack.what am I doing wrong?

here is direct link:http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt2231253&plot=short&r=xml

```
        string url = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=" + ImdbID + "&plot=short&r=xml"; 
        HtmlWeb source = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlDocument document = source.Load(url);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its no Html but a XML document you expect. Try this instead:

```
 string url = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt2231253&plot=short&r=xml";
 WebClient wc = new WebClient();
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(wc.DownloadString(url));
 Console.WriteLine(doc);
```